# Plot columns of data-frame based on conditions of other columns in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Below is my dataset:

```
    City    Product Spend_Year  Total_Spend
0   BANGALORE   Gold    2004    248006886
1   BANGALORE   Gold    2005    357076946
2   BANGALORE   Gold    2006    329375735
3   BANGALORE   Platimum    2004    138238363
4   BANGALORE   Platimum    2005    167115119
... ... ... ... ...
67  TRIVANDRUM  Platimum    2005    222789632
68  TRIVANDRUM  Platimum    2006    129408676
69  TRIVANDRUM  Silver  2004    14957733
70  TRIVANDRUM  Silver  2005    27465271
71  TRIVANDRUM  Silver  2006    31632500
```

I need to plot **City** vs **Total_Spend** while selecting one **product** and **Spend_Year** for all possible combinations.

*Example: Plot of **City** vs **Total_Spend** for Gold Product in the Year 2004.*

P.S.: In the data set I have 3 product categories and data is available for 3 years.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will make one plot for each combination. It should be easy to use matplotlib subplots to move them all into one figure.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for product in df['Product'].unique():
    for syear in df['Spend_Year'].unique():
        plt.figure()
        ax = df.query('Product==@product and Spend_year==@syear').set_index('City')['Total Spend'].plot()
        ax.set_title(f'Product {product} year {syear}')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `seaborn.FaceGrid`:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df, row='Spend_Year', col='Product')
g = g.map(sns.lineplot, 'City', 'Total_Spend')
```

Or you can use `groupby()`:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3,3)

for (k,d), ax in zip(df.groupby(['City','Spend_Year']), axes.ravel()):
    city, year = k
    d.plot(x='City', y='Total_Spend', ax=ax)

    # extra format with ax if needed
    ax.set_title(f'{city} - {year}')
```